# How to handle same item with multiple prices based on condition without configurable products?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, configurable-product, pricing

I am selling collectible cards.  Each card can have 5 different conditions (Mint, Lightly Played, Heavily Played, etc). Each condition will have different prices based on the condition and need to be inventoried/sold separately.

It seems that the core Magento solution is configurable products, but there are over 20,000 different cards/SKUs.  Do i really have to create over 100,000 different simple product just to achieve this?

I can't afford any $300 modules right now.  Does anyone have an alternate way to handle this scenario?  Thank you for your insight.

Using Magento ver. 1.9.2.4

Comment: this might be cheaper alternative for you https://www.envisionecommerce.com/store/advance-dependent-custom-option-in-magento.html

Comment: You can used simple product with custom options. May be it will work for you.

Comment: Custom options do not allow for inventory control.  I need that